# How can I make the first colum align with the 2nd and the 3rd line by line?

Tags: tables

Part of this program use a macro to type pseudocode.
But the macro did not provide tab to type comment at the right end.
I do the tab comment by myself using tabular environment (two versions shown).
But these two column do not align.
How can I align them?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{clrscode3e} % Macro by Cormen for typing algorithm in his book
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}


\title{check}

\author{author}
\maketitle


\begin{tabular}{lll}
\multirow{9}{*}{
\begin{minipage}[]{9cm}
\begin{codebox}
\Procname{$\proc{Insertion-Sort}(A)$} 
\li \For $j \gets 2$ \To $\attrib{A}{length}$ 
\li \Do
$\id{key} \gets A[j]$ 
\li \Comment Insert $A[j]$ into the sorted sequence.
\li $i \gets j-1$
\li \While $i > 0$ and $A[i] > \id{key}$
\li \Do
$A[i+1] \gets A[i]$
\li $i \gets i-1$
\End
\li $A[i+1] \gets \id{key}$
\End
\end{codebox}
\end{minipage}
}
& \begin{minipage}[]{4em}\vskip 3ex cost \end{minipage}   & \begin{minipage}[]{5em}\vskip 3ex times \end{minipage} \\
&  $c_1$  & $n$ \\
&  $0$    & $n-1$ \\
&  $c_4$  & $n-1$ \\
&  $c_5$  & $\sum_{j=2}^n t_j$\\
&  $c_6$  & $\sum_{j=2}^n t_j-1$\\
&  $c_7$  & $\sum_{j=2}^n t_j-1$\\
&  $c_8$  & $n-1$
\end{tabular}

\vskip 10ex

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\begin{minipage}[]{9cm}
\begin{codebox}
\Procname{$\proc{Insertion-Sort}(A)$} 
\li \For $j \gets 2$ \To $\attrib{A}{length}$ 
\li \Do
$\id{key} \gets A[j]$ 
\li \Comment Insert $A[j]$ into the sorted sequence.
\li $i \gets j-1$
\li \While $i > 0$ and $A[i] > \id{key}$
\li \Do
$A[i+1] \gets A[i]$
\li $i \gets i-1$
\End
\li $A[i+1] \gets \id{key}$
\End
\end{codebox}
\end{minipage}
& 
\begin{minipage}[]{4ex}
cost \\
$c_1$ \\
$0$ \\
$c_4$ \\
$c_5$ \\
$c_6$ \\
$c_7$ \\
$c_8$ 
\end{minipage}
& \begin{minipage}[]{5em}times \\
 $n$ \\
 $n-1$ \\
 $n-1$ \\
 $\sum_{j=2}^n t_j$\\
 $\sum_{j=2}^n t_j-1$\\
 $\sum_{j=2}^n t_j-1$\\
 $n-1$
\end{minipage} 
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to align the tops, bottoms, or centers (default)?  Also, I'm not sure chat good a tabular will do you here, other than provide 2\tabcolsep spacing between columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

both tables had to have the same design of columns. for this i suggest to use `tabularx` table environment. with using it the `minipage`s are not necessary anymore. also you should give a care to number of lines in the `multirow` cell and number by it spanned cells, they should be equal. beside this, also is necessary to consider vertical space above `\begin{codebox}`. it can be removed with `\vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip}` for more space between table rows i add package `makecell` and use their macros `\setcellgapes{2pt}` and `\makegapedcells`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{clrscode3e} % Macro by Cormen for typing algorithm in his book
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\title{check}
\author{author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

{ % for make a group in which is valid \makegapedcells
\makegapedcells
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X >{$}l<{$} >{$}p{22mm}<{$}
                            @{}}
\multirow[t]{9}{=}{\vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip} % <-- remove top vertical space of `codebox`
    \begin{codebox}
\Procname{$\proc{Insertion-Sort}(A)$}
\li \For $j \gets 2$ \To $\attrib{A}{length}$
\li \Do
$\id{key} \gets A[j]$
\li \Comment Insert $A[j]$ into the sorted sequence.
\li $i \gets j-1$
\li \While $i > 0$ and $A[i] > \id{key}$
\li \Do
$A[i+1] \gets A[i]$
\li $i \gets i-1$
\End
\li $A[i+1] \gets \id{key}$
\End
\end{codebox}
            }
    &   \text{cost} &   times               \\
    &   c_1         &   n                   \\
    &   0           & n-1                   \\
    &  c_4          & n-1                   \\
    &  c_5          & \sum_{j=2}^n t_j      \\
    &  c_6          & \sum_{j=2}^n t_j-1    \\
    &  c_7          & \sum_{j=2}^n t_j-1    \\
    &  c_8          & n-1                   \\
\end{tabularx}

\vskip 10ex
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X >{$}l<{$} >{$}p{22mm}<{$}
                                      @{}}
\multirow[t]{9}{=}{\vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip} % <-- remove top vertical space of `codebox`
    \begin{codebox}
\Procname{$\proc{Insertion-Sort}(A)$}
\li \For $j \gets 2$ \To $\attrib{A}{length}$
\li \Do
$\id{key} \gets A[j]$
\li \Comment Insert $A[j]$ into the sorted sequence.
\li $i \gets j-1$
\li \While $i > 0$ and $A[i] > \id{key}$
\li \Do
$A[i+1] \gets A[i]$
\li $i \gets i-1$
\End
\li $A[i+1] \gets \id{key}$
\End
\end{codebox}
            }
    &   \text{cost} &   times               \\
    &   c_1         &   n                   \\
    &   0           & n-1                   \\
    &  c_4          & n-1                   \\
    &  c_5          & \sum_{j=2}^n t_j      \\
    &  c_6          & \sum_{j=2}^n t_j-1    \\
    &  c_7          & \sum_{j=2}^n t_j-1    \\
    &  c_8          & n-1
\end{tabularx}
} % end of group
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, \setcellgapes{1pt} will make them appears equal.

Comment: @latra, your observation is correct. actually i didn't load the last version of tested code. now corrected. btw, this site has rule that instead sayed "tank you! you vote answer (by clicking up pen at top left side of answer) and from received answers, accept the one that best solves your problem. as far as I can see, by now you have never done this. please respect people which try to help you.